# TWI (Topographic Wetness Index) The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, saga

```
QGIS version: 3.22.9-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: a8e9e6fae5
Qt version: 5.14.2
Python version: 3.8.7
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Algorithm started at: 2023-01-31T12:17:11
Algorithm 'Saga wetness index' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'AREA' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'AREA_MOD' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'AREA_TYPE' : 0, 'DEM' : '/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/Kalimantan_DEM_Fill.img', 'SLOPE' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SLOPE_MIN' : 0, 'SLOPE_OFF' : 0.1, 'SLOPE_TYPE' : 0, 'SLOPE_WEIGHT' : 1, 'SUCTION' : 10, 'TWI' : '/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/TWI.sdat' }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/0b5c076cc5f14563b6b48572179867f8/KalimantanDEMFill.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/Kalimantan_DEM_Fill.img"
ta_hydrology "SAGA Wetness Index" -DEM "/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/0b5c076cc5f14563b6b48572179867f8/KalimantanDEMFill.sgrd" -SUCTION 10.0 -AREA_TYPE 0 -SLOPE_TYPE 0 -SLOPE_MIN 0.0 -SLOPE_OFF 0.1 -SLOPE_WEIGHT 1.0 -AREA "/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/5fcf2486448e4fc09ed8d7035881763f/AREA.sdat" -SLOPE "/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/fa8b3f96e88448fab2f3f4db338ec366/SLOPE.sdat" -AREA_MOD "/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/2fa51a7a610143baa259e5e6072702f0/AREA_MOD.sdat" -TWI "/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/TWI.sdat"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libio_gdal
library : io_gdal
tool : Import Raster
identifier : 0
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
____________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/Kalimantan_DEM_Fill.img"
Multiple Bands Output: automatic
Select from Multiple Bands:
Transformation: true
Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation


loading: /Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/Kalimantan_DEM_Fill.img



Driver: HFA

Bands: 1

Rows: 38828

Columns: 35022



Transformation:

x' = -438248.677341 + x * 30.000205 + y * 0.000000

y' = 10486705.733032 + x * 0.000000 + y * -30.000205


loading: Kalimantan_DEM_Fill



warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
Difference: 0.000000

using cellsize: 30.000205





____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libta_hydrology
library : ta_hydrology
tool : SAGA Wetness Index
identifier : 15
author : J.Boehner, O.Conrad (c) 2001
____________________________

Loading grid: /private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/0b5c076cc5f14563b6b48572179867f8/KalimantanDEMFill.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid system: 30.000205; 38828x 35022y; -438248.677341x 9436038.542816y
Elevation: KalimantanDEMFill
Weights: <not set>
Catchment Area:
Catchment Slope:
Modified Catchment Area:
Topographic Wetness Index:
Suction: 10.000000
Type of Area: total catchment area
Type of Slope: local slope
Minimum Slope: 0.000000
Offset Slope: 0.100000
Slope Weighting: 1.000000









pass 2 (122444238 > 0)
pass 3 (108782271 > 0)
pass 4 (101103983 > 0)
pass 5 (96534508 > 0)
pass 6 (93905133 > 0)
pass 7 (91552948 > 0)
pass 8 (89725012 > 0)
pass 9 (87599516 > 0)
pass 10 (85292433 > 0)
pass 11 (83863484 > 0)
pass 12 (82182415 > 0)
pass 13 (80596802 > 0)
pass 14 (79265504 > 0)
pass 15 (77917592 > 0)
pass 16 (76783021 > 0)
pass 17 (75647865 > 0)
pass 18 (74496528 > 0)
pass 19 (73289924 > 0)
pass 20 (72298745 > 0)
pass 21 (71297481 > 0)
pass 22 (70449037 > 0)
pass 23 (69446268 > 0)
pass 24 (68591461 > 0)
pass 25 (67603028 > 0)
pass 26 (66699392 > 0)
pass 27 (65866711 > 0)
pass 28 (65129881 > 0)
pass 29 (64174571 > 0)
pass 30 (63353149 > 0)
pass 31 (62658677 > 0)
pass 32 (62110349 > 0)
pass 33 (61359178 > 0)
pass 34 (60719897 > 0)
pass 35 (60113021 > 0)
pass 36 (59545959 > 0)
pass 37 (58876350 > 0)
pass 38 (58251791 > 0)
pass 39 (57493856 > 0)
pass 40 (56922534 > 0)
pass 41 (56352820 > 0)
pass 42 (55747855 > 0)
pass 43 (54996837 > 0)
pass 44 (54353514 > 0)
pass 45 (53875153 > 0)
pass 46 (53479141 > 0)
pass 47 (52853049 > 0)
pass 48 (52403356 > 0)
pass 49 (51870301 > 0)
pass 50 (51295073 > 0)
pass 51 (50730112 > 0)
pass 52 (50207625 > 0)
pass 53 (49831851 > 0)
pass 54 (49375973 > 0)
pass 55 (48945878 > 0)
pass 56 (48453809 > 0)
pass 57 (48009683 > 0)
pass 58 (47556446 > 0)
pass 59 (47120133 > 0)
pass 60 (46704433 > 0)
pass 61 (46335493 > 0)
pass 62 (45899450 > 0)
pass 63 (45438986 > 0)
pass 64 (45029419 > 0)
pass 65 (44625030 > 0)
pass 66 (44249061 > 0)
pass 67 (43825616 > 0)
pass 68 (43393073 > 0)
pass 69 (42980959 > 0)
pass 70 (42580782 > 0)
pass 71 (42146846 > 0)
pass 72 (41746536 > 0)
pass 73 (41432420 > 0)
pass 74 (41019194 > 0)
pass 75 (40598138 > 0)
pass 76 (40227441 > 0)
pass 77 (39910023 > 0)
pass 78 (39556654 > 0)
pass 79 (39198149 > 0)
pass 80 (38851591 > 0)
pass 81 (38558297 > 0)
pass 82 (38127262 > 0)
pass 83 (37835277 > 0)
pass 84 (37505933 > 0)
pass 85 (37107123 > 0)
pass 86 (36837082 > 0)
pass 87 (36465255 > 0)
pass 88 (36163081 > 0)
pass 89 (35877437 > 0)
pass 90 (35534142 > 0)
pass 91 (35243387 > 0)
pass 92 (34927120 > 0)
pass 93 (34652146 > 0)
pass 94 (34353429 > 0)
pass 95 (34099341 > 0)
pass 96 (33831742 > 0)
pass 97 (33587924 > 0)
pass 98 (33335252 > 0)
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/saga_cmd: line 9: 32405 Killed: 9 "$THISDIR/_saga_cmd" "$@"
Execution completed in 85813.22 seconds (23 hours 50 minutes 13 seconds)
Results:
{'AREA': '/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/5fcf2486448e4fc09ed8d7035881763f/AREA.sdat',
'AREA_MOD': '/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/2fa51a7a610143baa259e5e6072702f0/AREA_MOD.sdat',
'SLOPE': '/private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/fa8b3f96e88448fab2f3f4db338ec366/SLOPE.sdat',
'TWI': '/Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan '
'DEM/TWI.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /Users/agiegizawi/Documents/01_RESEARCH_AGIE/02_Kalimantan DEM/TWI.sdat
• /private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/2fa51a7a610143baa259e5e6072702f0/AREA_MOD.sdat
• /private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/5fcf2486448e4fc09ed8d7035881763f/AREA.sdat
• /private/var/folders/r1/r8lq9spn6vg3fbh8_ffphby40000gn/T/processing_IumDRp/fa8b3f96e88448fab2f3f4db338ec366/SLOPE.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question so that it contains a problem statement and a question.